# laravel middleware without use working

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, middleware

The question I have is that: I realized that the middleware in laravel runs before the router runs like an onion skin (something like that)
And we have a group of middleware called the web, whose work is something like making a session and also making CSRF_TOKEN / why I can use CSRF_TOKEN without using these middleware in the web.php file.
Or is the CSRF_TOKEN middleware something else?
(I use `csrf_token` in post forms) and my laravel version is 5.6)

Answer (score 0):

Middleware in Laravel runs after the router, when controller is already instantiated, but before specific controller action is performed.

Also you should not use CSRF_TOKEN field in your `web.php` file - middleware should contain common logic when dealing with incoming request (sanitizing data, restricting access etc), controller actions should contain route specific logic and provide a response. Your `web.php` file is setup to define routes, it should not contain code working with incoming request.

**Edit:** In case you are just wondering what `VerifyCsrfToken` does it just checks whether or not the incoming token in the request is a valid one.

Comment: You mean that ? If I do not use VerifyCsrfToken, there is a possibility of token fraud?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you use `csrf_token()` with your forms and AJAX requests and let this middleware take care of checking it for all routes in your app.